# How to easily edit a .class file

Tags: java, .class-file

I have a .jar file WHICH I DID NOT CREATE with many class files inside. I need to edit one specific class file. I have jd-gui. The unedited code of this class file, as shown by JD is:

```
package net;

import java.util.UUID;

public class a1b {
  XF a = aTt.e();

@aez
  public int getFoodLevel() {
    return aFO.q(this.a.aa).b();
  }

@aez
  public void setSlot(int paramInt) {
    this.a.aa.ba.b = paramInt;
  }
}
```

what I would like to change it to is:

```
package net;

import java.util.UUID;

public class a1b {
  XF a = aTt.e();

@aez
  public int getFoodLevel() {
    return aFO.q(this.a.aa).b();
  }

@aez
  public void setSlot(int paramInt) {
    this.a.aa.ba.b = paramInt;
  }

@aez
  public int getSlot() {
    return this.a.aa.ba.b;
  }
}
```

so i just want to add a simple function that returns the value of "this.a.aa.ba.b" (the player slot in the game this class file is in) (the jar file is obfuscated)

i am very new to java, i've tried a few different ways including recaf, however recaf doesnt work as the file is obfuscated and fails with "compilation error".

this compilation error does not occur due to my added function, instead there are a few other functions in there which i did not include as they aren't related to this question which stop it from compiling. when i delete the offending functions it compiles.

Comment: So `a` is not declared `private`? Then, you can simply add another class to the package providing you a method to read out the field, so you only have to compile your new class instead of the decompiled class.

Comment: Hi, I made Recaf. If the decompile-recompile feature isn't working (due to obf for example) you can use the assembler to make your changes. Its all on the documentation, which you can find via the help menu.

Comment: Thanks Col-E ill make sure to try that next time (the developer added the feature I needed)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit an obfuscated JAR file.

Obfuscated JAR files are created by the vendor with the express intention of preventing you from modifying the code.  And one of the things that a good code obfuscator will do is to transform the bytecodes in a way that makes it difficult for a decompilation tool (such as the one you are using) to produce valid (i.e. compilable) Java source code.

That is what has happened here.  The decompiler you are using has produced invalid Java source code.

What can you do?

- You could try a different decompiler.
- You could try reading the bytecodes yourself to work out what the correct code should be (for each of the errors) and then fix the source code.  (But that will be hard for a novice Java programmer.)
- You could ask the vendor of the software to provide you with a copy of the (real) source code.
- You could just stop.  If you read the license for the software you are trying to modify, you will probably find that it forbids decompilation, reverse engineering, and so on.

---

Note that since what you are doing could well be illegal, we would be ill-advised to assist you.  It would put us (StackExchange Inc, and the people who assisted you) in a legally awkward position.

Comment: I asked the developer, he doesn't care if I try modify the code and it's not illegal but he won't give me a copy of the code just in case I leak it. This is a pretty small an unofficial program and therefore they don't really have any legal backing. Eventually, by deleting a bunch of stuff recaf disagreed with, I finally managed to recompile it but when I tried to load it it told me the file might be cracked and therefore not allowed to launch. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: We only have your word for that.  Unless an official representative of the developer's is prepared to state that in public (and preferably in writing), the legal situation is unchanged.  (I have experience with certain large companies where an employee says something is OK in private ... only to have the company officially say the exact opposite.   You might trust this guy, but that is your business.)

Comment: Here's a thought.  Ask the developer to make the small change for you and provide you with a custom version ... appropriately obfuscated.  Alternatively, hire a Java developer (with "grey hat" skills) to do the modding for you.  Your organization will obviously need to indemnify them against possible legal consequences.  (Don't try to recruit them on StackOverflow ... an I am NOT interested.)

Comment: Stephen C they finally added the feature I was trying to add myself and it all worked out, basically did what you suggested I asked them to do. so it worked out

Comment: Add "persuasion" to your list of super-powers :-)